# AWSのネットワークACLでアウトバウンドルールを設定しない場合はどのような例があるか教えてください

Tags: aws, network

AWSのネットワークACLの設定はステートレスなため、インバウンドルールとアウトバウンドルールをそれぞれ設定する必要があると思いますが、インバウンドルールしか設定しないパターンはどのような例があるか教えていただけますでしょうか？

例えば、SSHやHTTP等はクライアント側から送信したときの返信が返ってくる必要があるので、インバウンドとアウトバウンドの両方を許可する必要があるという理解をしています。

クライアント側から送信するだけで結果を確認しないような例があるということでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

一応、UDPは一方通行の通信ですので、インバウンドのみ・アウトバウンドのみといった構成も可能です。